# Python. creating Pie chart using existing Object?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, pie-chart

I'm working on a dataset called 'Crime Against Women in India.
I got the dataset from the website and tidy up the data using Excel.

For data Manipulation and Visualization i'm using python (3.0) on Jupyter Workbook (5.0.0 Version). Here's the the code I worked so far.

```
    # importing Libraries
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 

# Reading CSV File and naming the object called crime
crime=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\aneeq\\Documents\\python assignment\\crime.csv",index_col = None, skipinitialspace = True)
print(crime)
```

Now I can see my data. Now I want to do is to find out what type of crime has the most value against Woman in India in 2013. That's simple and I did that  using the following code

```
   Type = crime.loc[(crime.AreaName.isin(['All-India'])) & (crime.Year.isin([2013])) , ['Year', 'AreaName', 'Rape', 'Kidnapping', 'DowryDeaths', 'Assault', 'Insult', 'Cruelty']]
print(Type)
```

Results shows like this.

```
Year   AreaName   Rape  Kidnapping  DowryDeaths  Assault  Insult  Cruelty
2013  All-India  33707       51881         8083    70739   12589   118866
```

Now , the next part is where I'm  struggling with it at the moment. I want to make a piechart for the type of crimes that has  the most values. You can see Cruelty('Cruelty by Husband or his relatives') has the most crime values than others.

I want to display 'Rape', 'Kidnapping', 'DowryDeaths', 'Assault', 'Insult' and 'Cruelty' on the Piechart (using matplotlib). Not 'Years' and 'AreaNames'.
This is my code so far

```
exp_val = Type.Rape, Type.Kidnapping, Type.DowryDeaths, Type.Assault, Type.Insult, Type.Cruelty

plt.pie(exp_val)
```

Not sure if my code is right. But anyways I got an error saying `'KeyError: 0'.

Can anyone help me with this and what is the right code for displaying Pie chart using existing object.

Comment: Since there is not a runable script, you may try this `exp_val = Type[['Rape', 'Kidnapping', 'DowryDeaths', 'Assault', 'Insult', 'Cruelty']].values.flatten();plt.pie(exp_val)`

Comment: Please see [mcve]. (Note that for the purpose of solving the problem, it is irrelevant whether you plot crime data from india or just some integer numbers in a dataframe).